# Angular prod image compression

Tags: angular, optimization, image-compression

Is there a build in Angular CLI way to compress all images? I've lots of SVGs exported via Sketch which do need to be compressed. I'm using Angular 6 and command `ng build --prod` doesn't seem to make any compression over assets folder.

Comment: I think that CLI tool invocation as a prebuild step is the most straightforward and easy way to do what you want.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am stuck in same situation.

Comment: @aje I've stopped on that I just optimized my SVG images in assets folder and left tham that way. Maybe it's better than hook on build since assets not that thing what changes constantly and you just need to optimize them once

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible: from the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure):

> **assets/** Contains image files and other asset files to be copied as-is
>   when you build your application

You might want check out compress libaries, [like ng2-image-compress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-image-compress).

Comment: It's a compression for uploaded files meanwhile I need to optimize static assets